# How do I make PMD also check my test code?

Tags: java, maven, pmd

I've got a Maven Java project that runs PMD to check the production code. How do I make PMD also check the test code?

I read several docs and guides, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: could this be helpful? https://pmd.github.io/pmd/pmd_userdocs_extending_testing.html

Comment: Unfortunately not. It explains how to _add_ a custom rule to PMD, and how to test the implementation of that rule. But I'd like to keep the rules as are and only apply them to some additional resources.

Comment: (mark your answer as correct, feels good man and it's legit)

Comment: @AsierAranbarri, StackOverflow wouldn't let me until today, you need to wait 2 days after posting the question before accepting your own answer. Anti-spam, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer myself. `<includeTests>true</includeTests>` within the `<configuration>` part of the PMD Maven plugin, as described in 
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/pmd-mojo.html#includeTests.